# How to "source" ~/.bashrc automatically once it has been edited?

Tags: macos, bash, alias

I would like to create an alias that does the following:

- Opens TextMate with `~/.bashrc` and allows me to edit it
- Once I close TextMate, "sources" `~/.bashrc` (so if I add a new alias, for example, it will be available immediately)

I tried the following:

```
alias b="/usr/bin/mate -w ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc"
```

but it doesn't work: when I close TextMate, the shell doesn't return.

Any ideas?

Comment: The described way works for me perfectly. Try again carefully :-)

What do you mean 'shell doesn't return'?

Comment: I never does this before, but I guess you can depend on the inotify feature. That's mean when the ~/.bashrc is updated, it trigger a command. example can be found on http://serverfault.com/questions/50127/how-to-automatically-run-a-script-when-the-contents-of-a-directory-changes-in-li

Comment: @ajreal: it would be difficult to get `inotify` to force something to happen in a few hundred running `bash(1)` instances.

Comment: By "shell doesn't return" I mean that I don't see the shell prompt anymore. If I just type `mate -w 1.txt` the shell prompt disappears (i.e. the shell "doesn't return immediately") until I close TextMate. Once TextMate is closed, the shell returns (i.e. I can see the prompt).

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to suggest it, but if this is a feature you *really* want, you can make something *similar* happen by setting the [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) variable to something clever.

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is run every time the shell shows the [shell prompt](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) So, if you're okay with the shells updating only after you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or execute a command, this should nearly do it.

Put `export PROMPT_COMMAND="source ~/.bashrc"` into your `~/.bashrc` file. Re-source it into whichever shell sessions you want the automatically updating behavior to work in.

This is wasteful -- it re-sources the file with every prompt. If you can get your editor to leave the *old* version in a specific file, say `~/.bashrc~` (where the first `~` means your home directory and the last `~` is just a `~`, a common choice for backup filenames) then you could do something more like (untested):

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="[ ~/.bashrc -nt ~/.bashrc~ ] && touch ~/.bashrc~ && source ~/.bashrc "
```

then it would `stat(2)` the two files on every run, check which one is newer, and re-source only if the `~/.bashrc` is newer than its backup. The `touch` command is in there to make the backup look newer and fail the test again.